# Cmake: libpng not dynamically linking correctly on a different machine

Tags: unix, linker, dependencies, cmake, libpng

On Ubuntu 13.04 VM, which was used to build the `sc` utility, the dependency looks like the below:

```
$ ldd sc | grep -i png
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb75c2000)
```

On my Fedora VM, the `sc` utility is not linking libpng correctly. It has libpng15 but it is trying to link to libpng12:

```
$ ldd sc | grep -i png
    libpng12.so.0 => not found
    libpng15.so.15 => /lib/libpng15.so.15 (0xb6f40000)
```

I am using cmake to build my executables, and I am using the default FindPNG cmake file. My executable is statically linking to ImageMagick, which is configured to use libPNG.

```
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS MagickWand MagickCore REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB)
find_package(Threads)
find_package(JPEG)
find_package(PNG)
find_package(LibLZMA)
find_package(OpenMP)
find_package(Cairo)

include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(sc
  ${LIBCAIRO}
  ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES}
  ${JPEG_LIBRARIES}
  ${PNG_LIBRARIES}
  ${LIBLZMA_LIBRARIES}
  ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}
  ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
  ${X11_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenMP_LIB}
  )
```

I've tried making my own FindPNG cmake to target libpng.so. I still get the same result...

Is there any way to make that so that my executable will link to whatever libpng is found on user's machine?

Comment: Have you tried using find_library?

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is nothing that I can do with cmake, and the problem is coming from libraries that I am linking against (Cairo and ImageMagick).

The reason that there are two libpng dependencies on the deployed system is that I am deploying a prebuild ImageMagick (statically) which is built on a machine with `libpng12`. I assumed that the deploy system will have Cairo and libpng, and it does, but it does not have `libpng12`. It has `libpng15` and Cairo, which is linking against it. Therefore, `ldd` shows that my executable is dependent on libpng12 and libpng15.

To resolve this, I statically link against `libpng12` and any libraries that are linking it.